# How to retrieve lost local cloud functions code

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have some cloud functions stored in my Firebase flutter app, these functions are working fine but unfortunately i've accidentally deleted the local node_modules file that contains the code for these functions so I am unable to edit them. Is there a way I can retrieve the code for my functions from firebase or will I have to write them all over again from scratch?

Comment: If all you lost was node_modules, then just do `npm install` again, as that is entirely just stuff downloded from npm, not your code.

Comment: @DougStevenson i lost my index.js which contains the code for the functions

Comment: @DougStevenson the link you provided answered what I needed, thank you!